# IIS 10 - Any way to set overrideMode="Allow" on website using powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

I need to allow "anonymousAuthentication" on one file only under a website, but adding the lines to web.config tells me I cannot override the parent setting.  I looked in the doc of applicationHost.config and if I manually add `overrideMode="Allow"` to the `location` line it should work(and it does) but I cannot find how to do this with powershell(we are trying to script the whole thing through ansible and powershell)

The website config in applicationHost looks like this:

```
    <location path="mywebsite"> <-line should be <location path="mywebsite" overrideMode="Allow" >
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

I tried Set-WebConfigurationProperty for the single file but it creates another section in applicationHost to control the setting, which is not what we want since the web.config stays locked, so future change would still have to be in applicationHost.config

Does anyone knows if it can be done?

EDIT: Some more infos: Here is what we want to work in web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="mainf.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="probe.txt">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There is no cmdlet to manipulate locking setttings. Run your script as administrator and use direct XML file manipulation to edit `applicationHost.config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many ways but only one powershell statement worked. You can try it.

```
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication -name 'sections["anonymousAuthentication"].OverrideModeDefault' -value Allow -pspath iis:\
```

[image]

Comment: This work, I also found out another command I will list below, but this works too so marking it as the right answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this works too:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Filter //System.webServer/Security/Authentication/anonymousAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\Sites -location "Website" -Metadata overrideMode -Value Allow
```